# MVC 3 - checking if form is valid (has passed client side validation)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using out of the box client side validation in MVC 3. At the client side, I want to detect if the form has passed client side validation. If so I want to display an busy indicator and disable the 'submit' button.

So I am looking for a form.isValid type property of a collection of error that I can query from js.

Any pointers.

Thanks

Pj

Answer (score 32):

You could use the following:

```
if ($('#yourform').valid()) {
    // the form passed client side validation
    // TODO: show busy indicator and disable submit button
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin - that's what I am looking for - where would that go in the page life cycle. What page level event is triggered post clientside validation.

Comment: @Phillip, you could do this in the form submit event: `$('#yourformid').submit(function() { if ($(this).valid()) { ... } });`

Comment: Thank you @Darin. That is right on the nail.
Philip please accept his answer as correct.

Comment: It is not working due to valid error: TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function.

Comment: I see this is an old post, but just for future reference `$(...).valid()` won't be a function unless you include a reference to the jquery.validate plugin on your page.

Comment: Should you call .validate() first? How do you know if it's been validated yet?

Comment: To **avoid form submitting twice** add `event.preventDefault();` check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127813/call-mvc-3-client-side-validation-manually-for-ajax-posts) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703817/submit-action-getting-hit-twice-while-using-jquery-ui-dialog) , hope helps some one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
            DisableSubmitButtons();
            console.log("All done");
        });
        });
    function DisableSubmitButtons() {
        $("#backButton").addClass("disabledbutton");
        $("#nextButton").addClass("disabledbutton");
    }


</script>
```