# Fire ASP.NET MVC2 client side validation from an anchor tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

I'm changing an existing ASP.NET MVC2 application which uses the MicrosoftMvcValidation.js etc. for client side validation.

```
<h2>Details</h2>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Add", FormMethod.Post, new { id="addForm" }))
   { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title) %>
        </div>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

The client side validation is working fine and dandy.

However, the designer wants to change the submit button to be a pretty anchor tag. I'm trying to submit the form using the anchor's onclick event i.e:

```
<a class="add-campaign-button-done" onclick="document.getElementById('addForm').submit();"><span></span></a>
```

The form submits, but client-side validation no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of jQuery you can do the trick, see this post : [Call MVC 3 Client Side Validation Manually for ajax posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127813/call-mvc-3-client-side-validation-manually-for-ajax-posts) for more informations and let me know if you need more help!