# MVC3 "Unobtrusive JavaScript" model validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation, progressive-enhancement

I used to make my ajax calls like this:

```
        form.bind("submit", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            form.ajaxSpin("large");
            form.ajaxSubmit({
                success: function(result) {
                    if (!b.ajaxFailure(result, true)) {
                        if(b.validateForm(form,result)) {
                            console.log(result); // TODO: something?
                        }
                    }
                },
                complete: function() {
                    form.ajaxSpin(false);
                }
            });
        });
```

so far my design is progressively enhancing.
and now I want to implement model validation on the client-side too, before making an actual request.

I included the `jquery.validation.js` plugin to the project, along with the latest `jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js` script.

Then I changed my code to:

```
        form.validate({
            submitHandler: function() {
                form.ajaxSpin("large");
                form.ajaxSubmit({
                    success: function(result) {
                        if (!b.ajaxFailure(result, true)) {
                            if (b.validateForm(form, result)) {
                                console.log(result); // TODO: something?
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        form.ajaxSpin(false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

which, I figured, would be exactly the same except it wouldn't make requests unless validation got through first.

the validation aspect works perfectly, entirely as expected, using the data attributes mvc sets from the model into my view's DOM.

the part where this fails and I can't figure out why, is that I'm back to not being ajax. the page just reloads, my `submitHandler` never fires (contrary to what [this link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) suggests)

I tried a few other common names for the `submitHandler` (`onSuccess`, `success`, etc) but none of them seem to be working.

Comment: Some good info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127813/call-mvc-3-client-side-validation-manually-for-ajax-posts/5131624#5131624

Comment: No problem, good luck with your app!