# MVC 5 Client side validation for ajax posts with click event not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have to implement client side validation with click event for ajax posts. I followed the below url:

[Call MVC 3 Client Side Validation Manually for ajax posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127813/call-mvc-3-client-side-validation-manually-for-ajax-posts)

I tried using this :

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $form = $('form');
    if($form.valid()) {
        //Ajax call here
    }
});
```

But the problem here is now the validation is working if there is invalid data. But if I give proper input also, the page is reloading and blank page is coming as a result.

I tried replacing evt.preventDefault() with return false. But there the validation is not working. Can anyone help me to solve this.

The thing is if drop down is not chosen, the validation message is coming. But If I give correct input, then output is not displayed.The page is refreshing.

I guess the problem is `evt.preventDefault()` . But validation is not working without this

Comment: just wanted to know; this `buttonId`, is a normal HTML button or is it a input type `submit` element? if it is a submit type then yes your form will get submitted the HTML form way hence reloading the page

Comment: `return false;` needs to be the last line in the script

Comment: show your ajax call too if possible!

Comment: preventDefault should be in the else part right?

Comment: @vijay, yes it is a input type submit

Comment: then in that case either you can change that input submit to normal button or Div with text OR you can add following line `$('#yourAjaxForm').bind('submit', function() { return false; });` before your `click` handler

Comment: Changed the submit button to normal button. didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the click of the button, I would recomend to use the following. The '*submitHanderl* is a callback function if the form is valid.

```
$("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        //Ajax call here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, for future reference, if you add `type="button"`, it will treat the button as a button and it will not submit the click. Same as doing an `event.preventDefault()` or an `<a>` tag's `return false;`