# MVC3 check is valid form in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC 3 - checking if form is valid (has passed client side validation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790198/mvc-3-checking-if-form-is-valid-has-passed-client-side-validation)

Is there a way to check if unobtrusive validation did pass/form is valid?

I need to show an alert box if the form is not valid. how would i do it in mvc3?
thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if (!$('#id-of-your-form').valid())
   alert('Invalid');
```

Should do the trick, MVC validation makes use of jquery.validate.js which attaches to the form.

Comment: +1 for mentioning jquery.validate.js

Answer (score 19):

If you want to check for it in View on server side, you could use 
`ViewData.ModelState.IsValid`